# create custom library with extends CI 3 core

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class

I have a custom library to check for an `AJAX` request, but it's not working.

The following code is my custom library:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Basic {

    // We'll use a constructor, as you can't directly call a function
    // from a property definition.
    public function __construct()
    {
            // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
           // $this->CI =& get_instance()
    }


    public function check_ajax(){
        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
           exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
    }
}


?>
```

and this is my controller:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();

    }

    function index(){
      $this->load->view('Vhome');
    }

    function article_list(){
        $this->basic->check_ajax();
        $res= array('status' => false,'noty'=>'Article is empty','res'=>array());
        $this->load->model('mquery');
        $articles=$this->mquery->read('articles','','','post_date DESC');
        if(!empty($articles)){
            $i=0;
            foreach ($articles as $key => $value) {
                $res['res'][$i]=$value->post_title;
                $i++;
            }
            $res['status']=true;
        }else{

        }

        die(json_encode($res));
    }

  }
  ?>
```

What's wrong?

This is the error message displayed:
[image: library ci error]

Comment: add `$this->load->library('basic');` in your controller `__construct` method

Comment: thanks 4 your comment, iam was load the library on autoload config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the CI object in your library to access it objects with :-

```
$CI = & get_instance();
```

after this you can use the CI classes like into your library like :-

```
    public function check_ajax(){
            $CI = & get_instance();
            if (!$CI->input->is_ajax_request()) {
               exit('No direct script access allowed');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank Manmohan, iwas update my custom library be this :

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Basic {

```
    protected $CI;
    // We'll use a constructor, as you can't directly call a function
    // from a property definition.
    public function __construct()
    {
            // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
           // $this->CI =& get_instance()
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }


    public function check_ajax(){
        if (!$this->CI->input->is_ajax_request()) {
           exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
    }
```

}

?>